# Authenticated Web Sockets Spring Boot 3

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, websocket, stomp

my team and me have been trying to migrate to Spring boot 3 with Spring Security 6 but found problems with the web sockets. If we remove the `@EnableWebSocketSecurity` annotation everything works fine, but the point is to only allow authenticated messages.

When adding the annotation, all we get is a `ExecutorSubscribableChannel[clientInboundChannel]` error on the frontend and an `access denied` on the backend.

We also tried to add a csrf token as explained on the official docs [https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/integrations/websocket.html#websocket-sameorigin-csrf] but the only thing we achieved was a `The request object has been recycled and is no longer associated with this facade` error message.

We would thank any help so far as we're completely lost :(

Here more details on our configs and how we're trying to create the connection:

SecurityConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
internal class OpaqueTokenSecurityConfig {
    @Value("\${spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.abc.token-uri}")
    var tokenUri: String? = null

    @Value("\${spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.abc.clientId}")
    var clientId: String? = null

    @Value("\${spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.abc.clientSecret}")
    var clientSecret: String? = null

    @Bean
    fun customIntrospector(): OpaqueTokenIntrospector {
        return CustomAuthoritiesOpaqueTokenIntrospector("$tokenUri/introspect", clientId, clientSecret)
    }

    @Bean
    fun filterChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain? {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy((SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
            .and()
            .authorizeHttpRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
         .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED))
            .and()
            .oauth2ResourceServer()
            .opaqueToken()
            .introspector(customIntrospector())

        return http.build()
    }

    @Bean
    fun corsConfigurer(): WebMvcConfigurer {
        return object : WebMvcConfigurer {
            override fun addCorsMappings(registry: CorsRegistry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**")
                    .allowedOrigins("*")
                    .allowedMethods("*")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

WebSocketsConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
@EnableWebSocketSecurity
internal class WebSocketConfig : WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    override fun configureMessageBroker(config: MessageBrokerRegistry) {
        config
            .enableSimpleBroker("/topic")
    }

    override fun registerStompEndpoints(registry: StompEndpointRegistry) {
        registry
            .addEndpoint("/ws")
            .setAllowedOriginPatterns("*")

    }

    @Configuration
    open class WebSocketSecurityConfig {
        fun messageAuthorizationManager(messages: MessageMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager.Builder): AuthorizationManager<Message<*>> {
            messages
                .anyMessage().authenticated()

            return messages.build();
        }
    }
}
```

Client on React:

```
let socket: CompatClient;
const client = Stomp.over(() => new WebSocket(`ws://localhost:8081/ws?access_token=${keycloak.token}`));
      
      client.onWebSocketClose = () => {
        // Do something
      };

      client.connect(
        {},
        () => {
          socket = client;
          // Do something
        },
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        (err: unknown) => console.log(err),
      );
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `@EnableWebSocketSecurity` will enable CSRF checking on the WebSocket. If you trace the code, you will find this CSRF interceptor is configured [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/9ec3e80e15c709502633447beeef36f957e2c4e4/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/socket/WebSocketMessageBrokerSecurityConfiguration.java#L95-L99). Therefore, I disable it by adding an empty one:

```java
    @Bean(name = "csrfChannelInterceptor")
    ChannelInterceptor csrfChannelInterceptor() {
        return new ChannelInterceptor() {
            @Override
            public Message<?> preSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel) {
                return message;
            }
        };
    }
```